# Why does XMLHttpRequest work with some websites but not others? Receiving NetworkError

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-get

The following code works and correctly prints the JSON at the indicated URL:

```js
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/", false);
req.send();
console.log(req.responseText);
```

If you change the website to Google, it does not:

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "https://www.google.com/", false);
req.send();
console.log(req.responseText);
```

You receive the following error:

[image]

This error seems misleading. Usually, when the word "network" is used, I think L3 or maybe L1/L2 but that's not the case here as we just proved the network is up and Google itself is accessible.

**Question**: Why does this not work?

**Bonus**: What is a strategy(ies) for obtaining more accurate error information from Javascript in a situation like this? The error seems to be either incorrectly labeled (perhaps that's opinion but at least from a network engineer's perspective you don't say "network" for a L7 problem anywhere I've ever worked) but I'm unsure how to investigate as "step into" doesn't actually work on the debugger.

### Update

I noticed that it seems to be a CORS error in the browser console. Currently investigating but it's not clear to me why this happens for one site but not another unless they are returning different CORS headers (maybe that's what's happening here?)

[image]

Comment: "unless they are returning different CORS headers (maybe that's what's happening here?)" — Yes.  A "Free fake API for testing and prototyping." makes it easy for you to do cross-origin work and a commercial website with adverts on it does not.

Comment: I hope you really do not use a synchronous XMLHttpRequest in real life.

Comment: Next learn about X-Frame-Options and get upset about those. :)

Comment: Negative - I just did it to make the example as short and simple as possible . That said, as someone who has done a lot of low-level coding, backend code, and automation - everything about Javascript upsets me . What a mess of a language. The Stackoverflow police can come for me with their opinion flag all they want but having experience in a dozen other languages in just as many different environments before coming to frontend dev I will die on the hill of, "Javascript and its accompanying frameworks are a disgusting mess and this is objective fact" hahaha

Answer (score 1):

A wide range of errors are filed under "Network error" for security reasons.

If Alice visited Mallory's website which used XHR to make a request to `http://company-intranet/` then it could fail for numerous reasons including:

- `http://company-intranet/` doesn't exist
- `http://company-intranet/` does exist but Mallory's website hasn't been granted [permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to access it.

The exception thrown doesn't contain information that allows you to distinguish why because (even if we limit things to just those two failure cases) the different would tell Mallory if the company intranet existed at that URL.

The would then tell Mallory that Alice worked for a company with an intranet at that URL which would let Mallory specifically target Alice for further attacks (both technical and social).

---

> What is a strategy(ies) for obtaining more accurate error information from Javascript in a situation like this?

More details are usually logged to the browser console in the developer tools. Usually as an error report immediately before the Network error that threw the exception.

The Network tab of the browser developer tools allows the full details of the request and response (if any) to be examined.